# Google Picker API - Word Vesion

Tags: google-api, google-picker

I want to use the [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs) to allow users to upload MS Word documents from their Google Drive to our system. I have everything working fine in on the client (javascript) but the problem is the URL I get from the Google Picker API (var fileurl = data.docs[0].url -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/[google_file_id]/view?usp=drive_web) doesn't link to an "MS Word" version of the file - it links to a Google Docs version.  How can I get the URL link to the actual MS Word version of the file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it thanks to this site https://appsevents.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-bypass-google-drive-viewer-and-create-direct-download-links.html

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=[FILE-ID]
```